# User terminates app forcefully: Registering this event

Tags: ios, xcode, uiapplication, termination

In my app I use background services so the method `applicationWillTerminate:` will not get called when the user terminated the app. Instead the method `applicationDidEnterBackground:` gets called when the user pushed the app into to background and when the user terminates the app completely.

The problem I am having is that I need to be able to distinguish between when the user has pushed the app into the background and when he actually quits the app because I have different code that needs to be fired for both events.

Is this possible in my case?

Answer (score 1):

The `-applicationWillTerminate:` method is called when the system is "nicely" terminating the application in an orderly fashion (ie, it's not being backgrounded for pending tasks or it told the OS those tasks are completed). This is distinctly different from "the user forcibly terminated the app", in which case your app won't receive *any* messages because it's just been summarily executed by a bullet to the head.

Are you certain you're correctly / fully participating in the background services? That is, are you certain you're correctly telling the system you've finished? You should edit your question and post the relevant backgrounding code. For example, if you're using `-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`, the docs say:

> If you do not call endBackgroundTask: for each task before time expires, the system kills the app.

...could this be your issue?

Comment: The background services are working fine. The app collects location updated without any problems. The reason I need to know wether the app is pushed into background or terminated is that when pushed into background the app registers a local notification. I do not want this to happen when the app is terminated.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm having trouble getting what you're asking. There is no effective distinction between your app being backgrounded or "quit" by the user; if it's not the active app, consider it terminated/backgrounded for *whatever* reason. For location services, this behavior is defined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10 Could you be more specific in exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not possible, but the only way I can imagine to distinguish between both of them is waiting to the next event. 
When the next event is a "start", you know that the last event was a kill.
When the next event is a "foreground", you know that the last event was a background.

This implies some processing at server, I know.

Hope this helps.